# Weak assembly changed to strong assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly, weak-references, strongname

I have a plugin structure which all is compiled using weak assemblies. I want to change this now but running into some difficulties.

```
interface.dll contains my interface for my plugins (IPlugin)
Load.exe will load all the plugin implementations which implements IPlugin
pluginA.dll contains a implementation of IPlugin
```

All assemblies is original weak assemblies.

I now want to change the assemblies to strong name assemblies.

After I have made the interface.dll and load.exe strong name assemblies I am unable to create an instance of the pluginA.dll IPlugin implementation, unless I have recompiled pluginA.dll to reference the new strong name interface.dll

Is there a way for me to set strong name on interface.dll and load.exe without being forced to recompile all plugins implementing IPlugin?

The reason I ask this, is that I have a lot of plugins and I don't have control of all of them. So I want to avoid breaking the plugin functionallity when I updated the interface.dll with a strong name.

I hope you can help me, and please do not hesitate to ask for further details if something is unclear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving an assembly a strong name is a hard breaking change.  You cannot patch it up with a config file or publisher policy.  So rebuilding the plug-ins is a hard requirement you cannot skip.

You didn't otherwise state the reason for deciding to do so.  There is no compelling one in a plug-in scenario.  A strong name provides a way to verify that an assembly is an *exact* match with the reference assembly that your program was built with. But, by design, you don't *have* a reference assembly for a plug-in.  So there's nothing to verify.

Comment: It sound's like there is no way I can archive my goal to strong name the interface.dll unless I at the same time make a strong name of all the plugins.

Comment: The pluginA.dll will reference the interface.dll at it fails to do so after I have made the interface.dll a strong name assembly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around this, unfortunately. The benefits you derive from strong-naming an assembly (most likely the reasons you are converting yours) are lost if you can reference simple named assemblies.

From Microsoft's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad.aspx):

> When you reference a strong-named assembly, you expect to get certain benefits, such as versioning and naming protection. If the strong-named assembly then references an assembly with a simple name, which does not have these benefits, you lose the benefits you would derive from using a strong-named assembly and revert to DLL conflicts. Therefore, strong-named assemblies can only reference other strong-named assemblies.